# HTTP: Headers vulnerability still showing after being added

Tags: web-application, .net, header

A web vulnerability assessment was done on our web app by a third company that specializes in security,

and we added common headers that we missing, and to check my headers internally before the third org could scan l used [an online tool for headers](https://securityheaders.com/)

when l check the headers are present and it's reporting fine.

Now the security org does the scan it shows the same error but minor changes that headers. below is the message

> The X-Content-Type-Options response header is not present. WAS reports
> missing X-Content-Type-Options header on each crawled link for both
> static and dynamic responses. The scanner performs the check not only
> on 200 responses but 4xx and 5xx responses as well. It"s also possible
> the QID will be reported on directory-level links.

this header is present, but somehow the error keeps showing;

one last thing some of the headers that are present are from links with the page ie CSS or js that have those missing script

**Edited**
if l inspect on the browser l can see the headers but if l access the file on its own then it shows the headers missing as in the image, can CSS and js have their own headers as well

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Headers responses may differ from URL to URL, try the get which requests were made by the third party company. Setting up headers depends on your technical stack. What webserver are you using? your app is a .net/java/php... app ?

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri .net

Comment: everything you need to know to set your IIS settings https://docubrain.com/kb/adding-http-headers-increase-iis-security#:~:text=To%20add%20a%20new%20HTTP,the%20header%20and%20click%20OK.